# LED lights of Christmas 3 volts

Tags: led

I want to make a simple electronic circuit to make some LED lights of Christmas 3 volts cause fades, phases, flashes, etc. How can I do this circuit without Arduino?

Thanks for your responses. 
[image: I add this picture asking what is the electronic component in the middle]

Comment: So basically, you want an intelligent blinky light without intelligence!

Comment: I want to use a simple circuit like those with 555.

Comment: You're not really on the right site, Luis. This site is for specific electronics design questions and answers rather than a "gimme the schematic" type of site. You can generally get what you are looking for for a couple of €/£/$ in bargain stores - although February is a bad time to go looking. If you want to learn electronics then there are a multitude of websites for this already and there's no need for anyone to write an article for you here.

Comment: Thank you but in those places I have not been able to find what I am looking for and that is why I am looking here for someone to kindly tell me how to do it.

Comment: If you are willing to go the AC route, you could use SCRs to create the fading effect. SCR can be driven by a pulse generator in order to implement different fading effects

Comment: Thank you, you would help me a lot if you give me the drawing of the electronic circuit.

Comment: That sounds very like "gimme the schematic"!

Comment: Yes, I want to explain something, I am a very old man that try to live each day the better as possible. Due to my conditions I have some problems to study new things, sorry if I annoying but I think it's something simple for you.

Comment: You need to spell out to yourself what you want to achieve. With simple timers and logic, you can build a sequencer, or a fader, but what you can get will be limited, and fixed once you've built it. If you want to generate multiple patterns, you'll need a programmable microcontroller of some sort, and you'll probably want to browse through the various project sites (like instructables.com) for a project that is near what you want, then you can modify, maybe using the code as is if you don't want to deal with that.

Comment: Thank you, I can do projects with Arduino, but I want it more simple and cheap.

Comment: Some ideas, but please make sure you understand the risk of working with mains voltage (230V or 110V can be deadly). Never touch the circuit when it is powered, and enclose it in a plastic, sturdy and sealed case. https://www.electroschematics.com/tag/led-flasher-circuits/ , http://www.electronic-circuits-diagrams.com/christmas-star-circuit/ . Not all these solutions can be adapted to work with LEDs.

Comment: *I can do projects with Arduino, but I want it more simple and cheap.* Then get a cheap Arduino clone board (from Ebay for example). I personally do not see how you could get a cheaper and simpler solution for a hobby project. Only if you're going to mass produce this design (and you're not) then there are simpler and cheaper microcontrollers available (Google "3 cent microcontroller").

Comment: I have some Arduinos but I want to learn to do it in other way.

Comment: I add a picture in the beginning asking what is the electronic component in the middle. Please let me know if you any have the answer.

Comment: The component in the middle that you're looking at is an Integrated Circuit, just like the microprocessor that powers your Arduino boards. The difference is that it's attached to the board in a way that looks strange. Chips attached to the board like this are called "Chip on Board" (google "glop-top COB" to see similar things). It's a way to save cost in mass-produced products, but is VERY expensive to get started with. It's practically impossible for you to know exactly what the chip is, but it's probably just as complicated as your Arduino.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: Here is a [Digikey search](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/integrated-circuits-ics/embedded-microcontrollers/685?FV=16%7C338537%2C-8%7C685&quantity=0&ColumnSort=1000011&page=1&stock=1&pageSize=25&pkeyword=micro) showing a few of these kinds of chips, these called [Wafer Level Package](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wafer-level_packaging).  One of those, this MAXQ8913 ["58 WLP" datasheet](https://4donline.ihs.com/images/VipMasterIC/IC/MAXM/MAXMS09593/MAXMS09593-1.pdf?hkey=EC6BD57738AE6E33B588C5F9AD3CEFA7) shows you the layout on the last page -- the chip connects directly to the board.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is directly asking for a free design.